# ScrollBar in LWUIT

Tags: java-me, scrollbar, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor, lwuit-list

How can I edit the style of the lists´ scrollbar?
I want to modify its width, mainly.
To change his colors I use the UIID ScrollThumb, is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Shai Almog shows me how to edit the `ScrollBar`.

Using the UIIDs "Scroll" and "ScrollThumb", I can customize my apps´ scroll. Modifying padding/background I can control the width.

There are so many examples in the LWUIT svn.